# Proper testing flow with Laravel?

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, testing, integration-testing

I am in the process of using Laravel to build an API for an IOS application.  I am running into major issues testing the web app using PHPUnit and the built in Laravel Testing.

My process is 1. a user has an account 2. a user needs to be authenticated to perform any actions.

Lets say that I have groups of users, and that one user (the owner) can manage members that belong to one of their groups.  I want to test the ability of a user to add other members to their group.

I have a testing method called testAddGroupMemberPass() which should

1. create a user (owner)
2. create a group and assign the owner
3. create a user to add to the group
4. assert that the owner has the ability to add that member.

   ```
   public function testAddGroupMemberPass()
   {
       // 1. create owner
       $owner = factory(User::class)->create();
       $token = JWTAuth::fromUser($owner);

       // 2. create group and attach user
       $group = new Group;
       $group->owner_id = $owner->id;
       $group->save();

       // 3. create the member to be
       $user = factory(User::class)->create();

       // 4. attempt attach the member to the group
       $this->edit('/groups/' . $group->id . '/add-member/' . $user->username . '?token=' . $token)
       ->seeJson(['success' => true]);
   }
   ```

To assert that an owner can add a user you have to first create the owner, secondly create the group, thirdly create the user that you want to add to the group, and then finally you are able to try to make the request to the API to actually add that user.

The problem is that various issues can be encountered in the first 3 steps that are totally unrelated to the process of adding a member to a group, such as username and email unique constraints.

So what is wrong with my current approach?  I've always been told that tests should be completely independent of one another so it wouldn't make sense to try and use users and groups generated by previous tests AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

You can abstract out `1`, `2`, and `3` to a base test class and use those same methods for the tests that test those specific pieces of functionality.

For example:

```
// TestCase.php
protected function createOwner()
{
    return factory(User::class)->create();
}

protected function createGroup($owner)
{
    // You didn't show this as a factory, but I figured you might want that
    $group = factory(Group::class)->create();
    $group->owner()->associate($owner);
    $group->save();

    return $group;
}

protected function createUser()
{
    return factory(User::class)->create();
}

// In the file you mention above (should be extending TestCase.php)
public function testAddGroupMemberPass()
{
    // 1. create owner
    $owner = $this->createOwner();
    $token = JWTAuth::fromUser($owner);

    // 2. create group and attach user
    $group = $this->createGroup($owner);

    // 3. create the member to be
    $user = $this->createUser();

    // 4. attempt attach the member to the group
    $this->edit('/groups/' . $group->id . '/add-member/' . $user->username . '?token=' . $token)
         ->seeJson(['success' => true]);
}
```

Those methods can be used in other tests like so:

```
// In UserTest.php (also extends TestCase.php)
public function testItCreatesAUser()
{
    $user = $this->createUser();

    $this->seeInDatabase('users', $user);
}
```

The fact is, if you need your world to look a certain way and you're doing some sort of functional or integration tests, then you need to encapsulate that logic somewhere. Moving it to a base class will help remove the duplicate functionality.

Comment: This will still result in the same issues though of constraint violations due to randomly generated users using the factory.  A user generated using factories may not be unique resulting in a constraint violation upon creating them with persistence.  There are 20 other cases for the groups and in each method they will also call the abstracted functions which each create new persistent users without actually ensuring that they are valid.  You know what I mean? I'm probably explaining this poorly and have exhausted myself with looking at it...

Comment: In Laravel, use the `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions` trait to handle that. A `Rollback` is performed after each **test**. https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/testing#resetting-the-database-after-each-test

Comment: So ideally that would work and was my original approach.  However, the transactions seemed to happen inside the actual tests.  So when I created a user using the factor that was wrapped in a transaction.  Then we I went to create the group, that was also wrapped in one, etc... so by the time I went to attach the owner group he had already been cleared by the transaction resulting in a foreign key constraint violation.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/kyle-mccarthy/b5e856157195605c711a#file-gistfile1-txt

This should help explain the issue further.... I have included the use DatabaseTransaction trait in the TestFile and the TestCase is being extended.

Comment: Can I see your entire test file and also post `TestCase.php`? Which version of Laravel are you using? It definitely does a rollback *after* each test.

Comment: Of course, anything that you think would clear things up.... https://gist.github.com/kyle-mccarthy/5241c4291b2d31819efc

The user is removed from the DB by the time it makes the get request to the application.

Comment: Not sure if this is a typo, but you have to `use` the Trait inside the class declaration. Add this after line 12 in `GroupControllerTest.php`: `use DatabaseTransactions;`

Comment: That has been removed for debugging purposes.  Using transactions will result in the following error illustrated in this gist... https://gist.github.com/kyle-mccarthy/ca835eef584e96531f32

Edit: to note that using transactions will cause all the tests to fail.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99749/discussion-between-tptcat-and-kyle).